# VBA: best way to delete all buttons except one

Tags: excel, vba

I have different buttons in Excel and I would like to delete all of them except some.

I run

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
```

but how can I declare to keep one (we may assume it is called "MyButton1")?

Comment: Post the code you've tried. Busse has been very generous in writing this for you - most people wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Do a For Each, by looping through ActiveSheet.Shapes you can see all the different buttons on your worksheet(s).  In the example below, it assigns `btn =` to the current button it's looking at.  If the name of the Button is NOT `"MyButton1"` then it is deleted.  The Next sends it back to the top to start again.

```
For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons
    If btn.Text <> "MyButton1" Then
        btn.Delete
    End If
Next
```

You can do this and change the "MyButton1" to whatever you would like.  Since I am assuming that's not the name of your actual button.  Also, if for some reason you only *wanted* to delete that particularly named button, you would just switch the `<>` with a `=`.  So it would read

`If btn.Text = "MyButton1" Then btn.Delete`

---

Edit -

Changed `btn.Name` to `btn.AlternativeText` to search for the visible text of the button instead of the object name itself.

---

Edit 2 -

I've removed ActiveSheet.Shapes as you had additional elements in the worksheet you didn't want deleted.  I have replaced the original code with `ActiveSheet.Buttons` and replaced `AlternativeText` with `btn.Text` to identify the Button Names.

Again, if you are not running this code on the sheet with Buttons, you will need to reference the workbook and worksheet first.

Comment: I get: the index into the specified collection is out of bounds. I only changed: `If btn.Name <> "myButton1" Or btn.Name <> "myButton2" Then`

Comment: Are you running the macro on the same sheet your buttons are located on?  If not, you'll need to change activesheet to Workbooks.Sheets("Sheetname").Shapes

For example, if you are using a workbook titled `Book1`, and a sheet titled `Sheet1`. Then the code would go:  `For Each btn in Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes` then the rest of the code

Comment: Yes. I am on the same sheet

Comment: I changed `.name`. to `.AlternativeText` so it actually shows the text on the button instead of the physical name of the button.  If you want to change it back to the actual object name, keep it `.name`, but I felt like you want the text the object shows.

As for the error, can you post all of your code you are running?  The For Each in Shapes should only show shapes that exist, so I am unsure why it's going out of bounds.  Edit your original post with all the code please.

Comment: @Thegamer23 `If btn.Name <> "myButton1" Or btn.Name <> "myButton2" Then` will match **all** buttons. `myButton2` is not equal to `myButton1` so it will satisfy the first part of the `If` statement and you will delete it. Change `OR` to `AND` to make that work.

Comment: I managed to make it work but it deleted me all the data validations elements

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Shapes` is very generic.  I didn't know you had different types of shapes/elements on there.  

I've updated my original answer again, and this time it is exclusively for Buttons.  Try it again.